# azcopy failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot use directory as source without --recursive or a trailing wildcard (/*)

Tags: azure, azcopy

Trying to copy a .vhd between two different storage accounts using SAS.  Getting error.  Can someone give me a hand please?  thank you much

```
azcopy cp 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/MyDisk.vhd?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=c&sp=rlx&se=2021-03-12T12:49:12Z&st=2021-02-14T04:49:12Z&spr=https&sig=oahRM1xDHkjgtEo5OjUv64vSPIjI%2BvyqVmdGN9demJc%3D' 'https://1sddq9uificcrb0t.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/MyDisk.vhd?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2021-03-13T01:02:49Z&st=2021-02-14T17:02:49Z&spr=https&sig=BXBocHkS%2FofwkhgdsvYccPEh0EA6Fpcu0LZd19%2FGwqw%3D'

Returning this error:

INFO: Scanning...

failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot use directory as source without --recursive or a trailing wildcard (/*)
```

Comment: What version of azcopy is this happening with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you copy the VHD file of the disk to another storage account.  You could try the command like this without `.vhd` suffix.

```
azcopy cp 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/abcd?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=c&sp=rlx&se=2021-03-12T12:49:12Z&st=2021-02-14T04:49:12Z&spr=https&sig=oahRM1xDHkjgtEo5OjUv64vSPIjI%2BvyqVmdGN9demJc%3D' 'https://1sddq9uificcrb0t.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/abcd?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2021-03-13T01:02:49Z&st=2021-02-14T17:02:49Z&spr=https&sig=BXBocHkS%2FofwkhgdsvYccPEh0EA6Fpcu0LZd19%2FGwqw%3D'
```

[image]

Or you can append the `--recursive` at the end of your command.